# How can I get lambda functions by tags in nodejs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'd like to find all AWS lambda functions by tag `(key=value)` in nodejs. I have read the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property but I can't find a way to search lambdas by tag name and value.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Resource Groups Tagging API to find (any) resources with specific tags.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const resourcegroupstaggingapi = new AWS.ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI();

exports.handler = async function(event) {
    const params = {
        ResourceTypeFilters: ['lambda'],
        TagFilters: [{
            Key: '<your-key>',
            Values: ['<value-to-match>']
        }],
    };

    try {
        while (true) {
            const resources = await resourcegroupstaggingapi.getResources(params).promise();

            resources.ResourceTagMappingList.forEach(r => {
                console.log(r.ResourceARN);
            });

            if (resources.PaginationToken === "") {
                break;
            }

            params.PaginationToken = resources.PaginationToken;
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return ""
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way for me to do that?

Not with a single API call. You have to do it in **two steps**:

1. Get the list of your functions using `listFunctions`
2. For each function, use its ARN to get the tags using [listTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listTags-property) and find the one you are after.

Comment: downvoted because this queries for a lot of data that you don't need. If you have 100 lambda functions in your account and you only need to return 2 you're making 200 requests vs if you do the accepted answer you're only making 3 requests.